# What happens to Fairy Chests when I get all the Runes?

Tags: rogue-legacy

Generally, every 2-3 generations, I'm managing to find and open yet another Fairy Chest, and thus am unlocking more and more runes for purchase. But what's going to happen when I unlock every rune? Does the game stop spawning Fairy Chests, or do they start to contain money, or what?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After you have all the runes you will get stat upgrades instead.

Comment: Permanent stat upgrades, or just for that character?

Comment: @SaintWacko I'm pretty sure all stat upgrades are permanent; kinda defeats the purpose of boss defeats, since that's what you get.

Comment: @fbueckert Yeah, I figured those were permanent, but that seems like a lot of free upgrades if the fairy chest ones are permanent as well.